# Java Project Output

Tags: java, string

Hi I'm finishing an assignment, however I'm getting the wrong output.

The goal of the project is to reverse a string.

So it's supposed to  take in a line of text as input, and outputs that line of text in reverse. The program repeats, ending when the user enters "Done", "done", or "d" for the line of text.

Ex: If the input is:

```
Hello there
Hey
done
```

the output is:

```
ereht olleH
yeH
```

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str;
        while (true) {
            str = scnr.nextLine();
            if (str.equals("quit") || str.equals("Quit") || str.equals("q")) break;
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                System.out.print(str.charAt(str.length() - i - 1));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

My current code is that however output is coming back as:

Input

```
Hello there
Hey
done
```

Output

```
ereht olleH
yeH
enod
```

Expected output

```
ereht olleH
```

Cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Um, `Quit`, `quite` and `q` are not `Done`, `done` or `d`

Comment: Besides, you are using `nextLine()`, and you check each line against the words with `equals()`. What do you expect?

Comment: I am working on the problem at the moment, but I want to make sure to use things that are allowed, so do you know arrays yet? Also, I would recommend using:
str.toLowerCase().contains("done") that way you don't have to check for Done, because it is lowercase. You can also use a do-while loop, but I will show that in my response

Answer (score 0):

```
    /*
        I don't know what you know, so I am not sure how your professor
        wants you to complete this, but I will do what comes to mind for myself.
    */

    //Instead of while(true) I like to use do while, which runs once automatically, and continues running until a condition is met
    do {
        str = scnr.nextLine();
        int i = 0;

        //This isn't the cleanest way to solve this, especially because it doesn't remove the space before done.
        //You could add more if statements for that, but the cleanest way would be to split the words into a String array
        // and check if any of the values of the array equal done, and remove it before flipping it around
        if(str.toLowerCase().contains("done"))
            i = 4;
        else if(str.toLowerCase().contains("d"))
            i = 1;

        while (i < str.length()) {
            System.out.print(str.charAt(str.length() - i - 1));
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    while (!str.toLowerCase().contains("done") || !str.toLowerCase().contains("d")); //This replaces that if statement from before
```

Comment: I am taking advantage of the fact that the "done" is always at the beginning. If the professor only cares about the output, you can do a few more if statements to get it working. However, if you are looking for a squeaky clean codebase (which I am guessing you are) you could add a boolean to detect if there is a done, try to remove it, and at the VERY END outside of the while loop you can choose to flip the text. As it is right now it will also flip the text if you hit enter without a "done", and that would fix that aswell

Answer (score 0):

you are using `.equals()` to check if the line is equal to one of your break words, but you are giving it the input `Hello there Hey done`, so it will not detect the the break word (ignoring the fact that you gave it done, not quit, I'm assuming that was a typo), so to detect that, you would either have to check if the line contains that word and if so, toggle a boolean and remove the word and any text after it from the line, e.g:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str;
    boolean end = false;
    while (!end) {
        str = scnr.nextLine();
        if (str.contains("quit") || str.contains("Quit") || str.contains("q")) { // checks if str contains the word, so if you write "hello quit" it will still detect it.
            str = str.substring(0,str.toLowerCase().indexOf("q")); // cuts off the string from the q.
            end = true;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            System.out.print(str.charAt(str.length() - i - 1));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

otherwise, you would just need to add the `quit` to the line after, and then it would work, so you would put in `Hello there Hey` then press enter, and then `quit`, and that will work.